# Verbos no infinitivo impessoal têm sujeito?

Tags: verbos, sintaxe

Orações com o verbo no infinitivo impessoal possuem sujeito?

Por exemplo, na seguinte oração:

> Querer é tudo,

Há sujeito? Se sim, qual seria ele e qual seria sua classificação?

Answer (score 4):

O teu exemplo é na verdade constituído por duas orações:

> **Querer** é tudo

Há uma oração subordinante em letra normal — “é tudo” — e em negrito temos uma oração subordinada, que é o sujeito de “é”, o verbo da oração subordinante.

Por sua vez, o verbo da oração subordinada — “querer” — está no infinitivo **impessoal** ou **não flexionado**, que normalmente não pode ter um sujeito foneticamente realizado. É isto que acontece no nosso exemplo. Vejamos o que dizem Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (*Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, Lisboa, 2014, p. 606; minha formatação, com a oração subordinada em negrito; omito as abonações):

> **I** O infinitivo conserva a forma NÃO FLEXIONADA:
>
> 1º) quando é IMPESSOAL, ou seja, quando não se refere a nenhum sujeito:
>
> > **Viver** é exprimir-se.
> >
> > **Jurar falso** é grande crime.
> >
> > **Amar os homens** é sempre uma alegria dolorosa.

O infinitivo impessoal tem no entanto um sujeito semanticamente implícito. Nos exemplos acima esse sujeito semanticamente implícito é qualquer pessoa, as pessoas em geral. Noutros casos é alguém ou algo concreto que pode ser “recuperado” do contexto. Os exemplos seguintes são da *Gramática do Português*  da Fundação Calouste Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, tomo II, p. 1942-46;  minha formatação, com a oração subordinada em negrito; indico entre colchetes o sujeito implícito, que obviamente não é dito nem escrito, e em itálico o elemento que o permite “recuperar”):

> *Nós* esquecemo-nos de **[nós] comprar o pão**
>
> O professor aconselhou-*te* a **[tu] concorrer a uma bolsa**
>
> Ocorreu-*nos* **[nós] fazer uma pergunta ao professor**

Existem ainda alguns casos em que o infinitivo impessoal admite um sujeito explicito, que é correferente com o da oração subordinante e tem de vir depois do verbo. O exemplo é da *Gramática do Português* (p. 1934):

> Os *funcionários* querem **levar eles as reivindicações ao patrão**

Answer (score 1):

Quando não houver um sujeito definido:

> Estudar é importante!
>   Ser feliz é um bom objetivo de vida.

"Estudar" não é sujeito?

Comment: Bem-vindo à comunidade. *Estudar* é o sujeito do verbo *ser* no teu exemplo, e está perfeitamente definido. Mas isto aqui é para responder, não é para perguntar

Comment: Talvez mais importante. A pergunta é sobre o verbo do infinitivo: sim *estudar* é o sujeito de *é*; mas a pergunta é, adaptando ao teu exemplo, sobre o sujeito de "estudar".

Answer (score -2):

No caso específico, o sujeito é indeterminado. Há três tipos de sujeito indeterminado: Com verbo na 3ª pessoa do plural, com verbo ativo  na 3ª  pessoa do singular, seguido do pronome se e com o verbo no infinitivo impessoal.
A regra completa pode ser observada no [Só Português](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint8.php):

> Sujeito Indeterminado: é aquele que, embora existindo, não se pode
>   determinar nem pelo contexto, nem pela terminação do verbo. Na língua
>   portuguesa, há três maneiras diferentes de indeterminar o sujeito de
>   uma oração:
>
> a) Com verbo na 3ª pessoa do plural:
>
> O verbo é colocado na terceira pessoa do plural, sem que se refira a
>   nenhum termo identificado anteriormente (nem em outra oração):
>
> Por Exemplo:
>
> Procuraram você por todos os lugares. Estão pedindo seu documento na
>   entrada da festa.
>
> b) Com verbo ativo  na 3ª  pessoa do singular,
>   seguido do pronome se:
>
> O verbo vem acompanhado do pronome se, que atua como índice de
>   indeterminação do sujeito. Essa construção ocorre com verbos que não
>   apresentam complemento direto (verbos intransitivos, transitivos
>   indiretos e de ligação). O verbo obrigatoriamente fica na terceira
>   pessoa do singular.
>
> Exemplos:
>
> Vive-se melhor no campo. (Verbo Intransitivo) Precisa-se de técnicos
>   em informática. (Verbo Transitivo Indireto) No casamento, sempre se
>   fica nervoso. (Verbo de Ligação) Entendendo a Partícula Se
>
> As construções em que ocorre a partícula se podem apresentar algumas
>   dificuldades quanto à classificação do sujeito.
>
> Veja:
>
> a) Aprovou-se o novo candidato.
>
> ```
>                                  Sujeito
>
> Aprovaram-se os novos candidatos.
>
>                                      Sujeito
> ```
>
> b) Precisa-se de professor. (Sujeito Indeterminado)
>
> ```
> Precisa-se de professores. (Sujeito Indeterminado)
> ```
>
> No caso a, o se é uma partícula apassivadora e o verbo está na voz
>   passiva sintética, concordando com o sujeito. Observe a transformação
>   das frases para a voz passiva analítica:
>
> O novo candidato foi aprovado.
>
> ```
>      Sujeito
> ```
>
> Os novos candidatos foram aprovados.
>
> ```
>        Sujeito
> ```
>
> No caso b, se é índice de indeterminação do sujeito e o verbo está na
>   voz ativa. Nessas construções, o sujeito é indeterminado e o verbo
>   fica sempre na 3ª pessoa do singular.
>
> c) Com o verbo no infinitivo impessoal:
>
> Por Exemplo:
>
> Era penoso estudar todo aquele conteúdo. É triste assistir a estas
>   cenas tão trágicas. Obs.: quando o verbo está na 3ª pessoa do plural,
>   fazendo referência a elementos explícitos em orações anteriores ou
>   posteriores, o sujeito é determinado.
>
> Por Exemplo:
>
> Felipe e Marcos foram à feira. Compraram muitas verduras.    Nesse
>   caso, o sujeito de compraram é eles (Felipe e Marcos). Ocorre sujeito
>   oculto."

Já no caso do infinitivo, há duas possiblidades: infinitivo pessoal e infinitivo impessoal. Citando a [Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/concordancia-verbal-com-verbos-no-infinitivo/):

> Para que seja feita uma correta concordância verbal com verbos no
>   infinitivo, precisamos compreender que o infinitivo pessoal é
>   flexionado e que o infinitivo impessoal não é flexionado.
>
> Verbo encontrar - Infinitivo pessoal (flexionado): (Eu) encontrar (Tu)
>   encontrares (Ele) encontrar (Nós) encontrarmos (Vós) encontrardes
>   (Eles) encontrarem
>
> Verbo encontrar - Infinitivo impessoal (não flexionado): encontrar
>
> Concordância verbal com infinitivo pessoal ou flexionado
>
> O infinitivo pessoal deverá ser usado:
>
> Sempre que há um sujeito expresso de forma clara e inequívoca, mesmo
>   em orações reduzidas.
>
> - Isto é para eu fazer durante o intervalo.
> - Isto é para tu fazeres durante o intervalo.
> - Isto é para nós fazermos durante o intervalo.
>
> Quando se quiser definir o sujeito através do verbo.
>
> - Acho melhor acabares o trabalho rápido.
> - Acho melhor acabarmos o trabalho rápido.
>
> Quando há indeterminação do sujeito, sendo utilizada a 3.ª pessoa do
>   plural.
>
> - Ouvi jurarem fidelidade ao novo rei.
> - Vi maltratarem os trabalhadores sem nenhum motivo.
>
> Quando o sujeito da segunda oração é diferente do sujeito da oração
>   anterior, podendo este se encontrar ou não claramente expresso.
>
> - A professora não viu os alunos copiarem no teste.
> - O diretor mandou os empregados participarem na reunião.
> - Nossa irmã trouxe um livro para nós lermos.
>
> Quando o verbo no infinitivo assume a função de sujeito da oração.
>
> - O fazermos tudo o que é preciso às vezes é cansativo.
> - O trabalharem pouco é desmotivador.
>
> Concordância verbal com infinitivo impessoal ou não flexionado
>
> O infinitivo impessoal deverá ser usado:
>
> Quando não houver um sujeito definido.
>
> - Estudar é importante!
> - Ser feliz é um bom objetivo de vida.
>
> Com sentido imperativo.
>
> - Parar!
> - Respeitar os mais velhos.
>
> Quando o verbo tiver regência de uma preposição, assumido a função de
>   complemento do substantivo, do adjetivo ou do verbo na oração.
>
> - Foram obrigados a passar fome por causa da crise financeira.
> - Fui impedida de dar minha opinião.
>
> Quando o verbo tiver regência da preposição a, assumido valor de
>   gerúndio.
>
> - Os meninos estão a nadar muito bem.
> - Ficaram a ver o filme em silêncio.
>
> Em locuções verbais, porque é sempre o verbo auxiliar que concorda com
>   o sujeito.
>
> - Os especialistas conseguirão estudar as características daqueles animais.
> - Ainda bem que meus pais puderam pagar minha faculdade.
>
> Com alguns verbos causativos e sensitivos que não formam locução
>   verbal (mandar, fazer e deixar, ver, sentir, ouvir) em conjunto com um
>   pronome oblíquo átono, mesmo quando há sujeitos diferentes nas frases.
>
> - Vi-os correr rapidamente.
> - Mandaram-na começar a trabalhar.
>
> Concordância verbal com infinitivo impessoal ou pessoal
>
> Quando o sujeito é o mesmo nas duas orações, é facultativa a escolha
>   do infinitivo pessoal ou impessoal, mesmo que o sujeito esteja oculto.
>   Contudo, nestas situações, há uma maior preferência dos falantes pela
>   forma no singular.
>
> - Viemos para transmitir as palavras do diretor.
> - Viemos para transmitirmos as palavras do diretor.
> - Lá estarão para resolver o problema.
> - Lá estarão para resolverem o problema.
>
> Quando o verbo se encontra na voz passiva ou na voz reflexiva, sendo
>   um verbo pronominal, ou quando for um verbo de ligação, é facultativa
>   a escolha do infinitivo pessoal ou impessoal. Contudo, nestas
>   situações, há uma maior preferência dos falantes pela forma no plural.
>
> - Os atletas treinaram muito para se tornarem os melhores.
> - Os atletas treinaram muito para se tornar os melhores.
> - Foram informadas as decisões a serem tomadas imediatamente.
> - Foram informadas as decisões a ser tomadas imediatamente.
>
> Com alguns verbos causativos e sensitivos que não formam locução
>   verbal (mandar, fazer e deixar, ver, sentir, ouvir) e que não aparecem
>   em conjunto com um pronome oblíquo átono, é facultativa a escolha do
>   infinitivo pessoal ou impessoal.
>
> - Deixei entrar as crianças.
> - Deixei entrarem as crianças.